# Laravel 4 eager loading issues with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables, items and users. A User can have multiple Items and an Item can be owned by one User.

My two tables have many fields but are linked by:

```
Item
----
ownerID

User
----
id
```

These are the fields that link the two tables together and they are set in my database with a foreign key.

Here is a shortened version of the two models:

```
class Item extends Eloquent {
    public function owner()
    {   
        return $this->belongsTo('User','id');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Item', 'ownerID');
    }
}
```

So, I want to get all of my Items and eager load the owner. This is my code in my Controller:

```
class ItemsController extends BaseController {
    public function all(){
        $items = Item::with('owner')->get();
        return $items;
    }
}
```

(I am returning `$items` so I can debug the output)

However, this is what I get as my output:

```
[
    {
        "active":"1",
        "categoryID":"1",
        "created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "description":"Just a test item",
        "endDate":"2014-03-01 21:46:07",
        "id":"32",
        "name":"Test Item",
        "owner":null,
        "ownerID":"1",
        "section":"0",
        "updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
]
```

I don't understand why owner is null? User ID 1 exists in my database so why is it null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your function in `Item`

```
public function owner()
{   
    return $this->belongsTo('User','id');
}
```

It indicates that, the `foreign key` in the `items` table is `id` which is being used for relationship with `users` table but you have used `ownerId` as the `foreign key` in the `items` table which is the `primary key` of `users` table.

So, it should be

```
public function owner()
{   
    // This model (child) with a local-key/field ownerId
    // in it's corresponding table(items) belongs to/relates to the
    // user model (parent) with primary-key id in corresponding (users) table
    return $this->belongsTo('User','ownerID');
}
```

While using `belongsTo/reverse` the second argument passed to the function is the referencing key (child-key/local-key) in the current table and here, `items` is the current table, which has the referencing key `ownerId` as it's `local-key` which relates to the `id` field of `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Item extends Eloquent {
    public function owner()
    {   
        return $this->belongsTo('User','ownerID');
    }
}
```